# How to give this table a border-radius?

Tags: php, css, ajax

How do I give this table a border radius of 5px? The css is in the code with the php ajax file.

```
<table border=';
$form_questions_list.='2px align=';
$form_questions_list.='center>
```

I've never seen CSS used this way. Can you tell me how to adjust this?

Here is the full function code:

```
// AJAX function to load updated survey question List
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_show_updated_question_list', 'show_updated_question_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_show_updated_question_list', 'show_updated_question_list');
function show_updated_question_list(){

global $wpdb;
$available_questions = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT question_ID, question_text FROM dm_form_questions");
$form_questions_list = '';

$form_questions_list.='<h1>Add your review questions here:</h1>
<table border=';
$form_questions_list.='2px align=';
$form_questions_list.='center>
<th style="background-color: #333; color: #FFF; font-size: 15px">Question Text</th>
<th style="background-color: #AFA; font-size: 15px">Edit</th>
<th style="background-color: #FAA; font-size: 15px">Delete</th>';
foreach ($available_questions as $key) {
    $form_questions_list.='<tr><td  style="text-align: left; width: 500px; padding: 0 5px;">'.$key->question_text.'</td><td><input type=';
    $form_questions_list.= 'button value=';
    $form_questions_list.='Edit id=';
    $form_questions_list.=$key->question_ID;
    $form_questions_list.=' onclick=';
    $form_questions_list.='edit_question_text(';
    $form_questions_list.=$key->question_ID;
    $form_questions_list.=') ></td>';
    $form_questions_list.='<td><input type=';
    $form_questions_list.= 'button value=';
    $form_questions_list.='Delete id=';
    $form_questions_list.=$key->question_ID;
    $form_questions_list.=' onclick=';
    $form_questions_list.='delete_question_text(';
    $form_questions_list.=$key->question_ID;
    $form_questions_list.=')></td>';
    $form_questions_list.='</tr>';
    }

    $form_questions_list.='</table>';
    echo $form_questions_list;
    die();
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: my suggestion is first use inspect element of the page of the WP page of this table and see which file the css is associated and on which element they have render the style, so accordingly you can override it from that.

Comment: I did that. The CSS is with the code in the ajax file.  Basically, I want to know how to make this border have: border-radius: 5px;

Comment: You've never seen CSS used that way because that's not how it's meant to be used. `border` is a very old attribute from the late 1990s and expects an integer ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)). Similar case with `align`. Nothing here is related to CSS (save for the bogus "px" suffix, which is wrong here).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `id` to the table.

**For example:**

```
echo "<table id=\"info_table\" border=2>";
```

Then add this CSS code to the head of you HTML document, or use it externally using a CSS file.

**Code:**

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  #info_table {
    Code: whatever;
  }
</style>
```

This allows you to style the table using CSS with a combination of PHP.

Let me know if this helped !

Comment: Where should I add the echo in the php file? I just updated my post to show the full function.

Comment: Try placing it at the top ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any CSS being used in this code.  It's just table element properties:  All you should have to do is add a style to the table.

```
<table style='border-radius: 5px;' border=';
$form_questions_list.='2px align=';
$form_questions_list.='center>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it immediately deactivates the WP plugin and does not allow me to reactivate it.